# Set up dependencies created by pybind11 when creating exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, pybind11

I used pybind11 to expose some libraries in C to python through a wrapper. When I created a GUI with tk, the py script works well. But when I converted the GUI into an exe, the exe created successfully but I got errors with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Control.py36' when running the exe, the pyd was created from C and located in Control\py36\Release. How do I add this module when creating the exe file?